Cpp Boost Library + Gauss Konrad Numerical Integration
I am able to implement a simple numerical integration using the boost Cpp Gauss-Konrad Gaussian quadrature routine, as indicated for example in:
https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/gauss_kronrod.html
However, I need to use this a routine in my code where a parameter continually changes, and is to be dynamically supplied in the code.
auto f2 = [](double t) { return std::exp(-t*t / 2)*std::cos(PAR*t); }; 

int main(){  
  double result, error;
  double PAR;
  double PI = M_PI; 
  result = gauss_kronrod<double, 15>::integrate(f2, 0, PI, 5, 1e-9, &error);
  // how do I supply PAR here? 
  printf("result =%.15lf, error = %.15lf\n",result,error);
  return 1;
}

I would appreciate if you help me on how to send PAR into the integrator.
Best,

CAVEAT
What does PAR depend on?
If it depends on anything but t, f2 will no longer have referential transparency. Most (all?) algorithms for numerical integration depend on this property to produce valid/reliable results.
Solution
Assuming PAR is constant during the calculation, but not necessarily for separate calculations, you can "inject" it by capturing into the f2 lambda:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/math/quadrature/gauss_kronrod.hpp>
#include <fmt/format.h>

auto run(double PAR) {
    auto f2 = [PAR](double t) {
        return std::exp(-t * t / 2) * std::cos(PAR * t);
    };

    double //
        error{},
        result = boost::math::quadrature::gauss_kronrod<double, 15>::integrate(f2, 0, M_PI, 5, 1e-9, &error);

    return std::pair(result, error);
}

int main() {
    for (auto PAR = 0.1; PAR < 2; PAR += 0.1) {
        auto [result, error] = run(PAR);
        fmt::print("PAR={:0.3f}: result={:.15f}, error={:.15f}\n", PAR, result, error);
    }
}

Prints
PAR=0.100: result=1.245079509637768, error=0.000000000009569
PAR=0.200: result=1.226865407508615, error=0.000000000011623
PAR=0.300: result=1.197074079052475, error=0.000000000015290
PAR=0.400: result=1.156528114965293, error=0.000000000020950
PAR=0.500: result=1.106329253137584, error=0.000000000029169
PAR=0.600: result=1.047811789441615, error=0.000000000040723
PAR=0.700: result=0.982487154732482, error=0.000000000056641
PAR=0.800: result=0.911982619962842, error=0.000000000078248
PAR=0.900: result=0.837977343960746, error=0.000000000107209
PAR=1.000: result=0.762139033182406, error=0.000000000145586
PAR=1.100: result=0.686064340253099, error=0.000000000195876
PAR=1.200: result=0.611225802257073, error=0.000000000261055
PAR=1.300: result=0.538927636504852, error=0.000000000344597
PAR=1.400: result=0.470272106858060, error=0.000000000450471
PAR=1.500: result=0.406137490816092, error=0.000000000051078
PAR=1.600: result=0.347167963640086, error=0.000000000043414
PAR=1.700: result=0.293775018511569, error=0.000000000023432
PAR=1.800: result=0.246149405919610, error=0.000000000015520
PAR=1.900: result=0.204282039978266, error=0.000000000081663


Hi, Thanks, this worked very well for me. I just had to change a few statements involving fmt and pair, but I am able to change PAR between two calculations using the "injecting" trick you shared.
Of course, during the calculation of the integral PAR remains constant.
Thanks again!
